# INSERT INTO button only inserts once

Tags: vba, ms-access, insert-into

Private Sub btnMissingModels_Click()

```
' Define variables
Dim IDToUpdate As String
Dim m_strSQL As String

' Grab ID
IDToUpdate = Me.FINLDATA_ID.Value

' INSERT ID and missing model - only works once (for T300 - 0000300) and doesn't ignore 'Removed' models
m_strSQL = "INSERT INTO [FINLDATA MODELS] (FINLDATA_ID, MODEL)" & _
        "SELECT '" & IDToUpdate & "', MODEL FROM T_MODELS_LIST WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT MODEL FROM [FINLDATA MODELS] WHERE [FINLDATA MODELS].MODEL = T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL)"

RunSQL m_strSQL

' Refresh the form display
Me.F_EDIT_ENTRIES_MODEL_SUB.Form.Requery
```

End Sub

The button works well however it only works once. For example, I click it, it adds the FINLDATA_ID and first MODEL which doesn't exist in FINLDATA MODELS but if I click it again it doesn't then add the next missing MODEL.

Also I would like to add a second WHERE condition but cannot seem to get it to work using 'AND' I have tried a range of syntax but none seem to work. I thought it would work WHERE (condition 1) AND (condition 2). The second condition is:

WHERE (((T_MODELS_LIST.REMOVED)=No)).

This filters out all superseded models. I have used this condition in previous queries and it has worked well.

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: What is RunSQL? If it is a custom function, please share that code as that is probably where your error is coming from.  If it's supposed to be DoCmd.RunSQL, I have no idea how it is working the first time.

Comment: I do not have much database experience so please be patient with me. I am currently updating a database that has been around since 2002, I have no previous knowledge and have been referring previous code to learn.

Current buttons all define LETTERHERE_strSQL as a string and then just RunSQL LETTERHERE_strSQL.

Comment: [Does this help clarify?](https://i.imgur.com/LdduhmQ.png).

Comment: Did you change the ID before clicking the button a second time? If not, that would explain that it can't insert the second record (with the same ID).

Comment: ID will remain constant as it grabs it from the form I am in and the form doesn't change.

Tomorrow I will try hard code the ID and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix your problem, but the library being used should be specified.  Since it looks like you are using native access libraries this will be the DAO library so change the Dim statements in RunSQL as follows:

```
Dim dbs as DAO.Recordset
Dim qdfSQL as DAO.QueryDef
```

Sometimes not specifying the library can cause issues let me know if this changes anything.

Comment: Thanks, I found [this](https://i.imgur.com/LdduhmQ.png). Does it clarify much? Sometimes with other things I have done errors have pointed there...

Should I be adding these to the private code for the button?